# How to Have Two PWM Signals with Adjustable Duty Cycle

Tags: pwm, timer, stm32f407

I am using Mosfets as switches in half bridge application. I use STM32F407VG as PWM generator. I used TIM1(TIM1 CH1 and TIM1 CH1N) in order to generate two complementary PWM signals to switch Mosfets. I wanted to control duty cycle from %10 to %50 to control output power. I managed to control duty cycle with buttons(+,- buttons).

My first problem was that i wanted same duty cycle in both PWM signals. I could not do it using only TIM1 because when i adjust duty cycle to %10, only one of the PWM had %10 other PWM had much more which is completely normal. I decided to have two different timers to have same duty cycle.

So i used TIM1 and TIM8 which are advanced timers. I choose them because i wanted to have dead time insertion. I enabled TIM1 CH1 CH1N and TIM8 CH1 CH1N but i only wired CH1 pins so i would have same duty cycles.

i succeeded to have same duty cycles but this time i am having another struggle. PWM signals are not complementary.

[image]

[image]

My signals are like in the picture above when the duty cycle is %50. Two PWMs are intersecting. I want to have two complementary PWMs with adjustable duty cycle and frequency.

How can i deal with this situation ?

Comment: https://hasanyavuz.ozderya.net/?p=437

Comment: @BruceAbbott I know this website. I already did what he had done. As i told in my question i could not have same duty cycles when i tried to adjust duty cycyle.

Comment: there are vids on that on yt. Usually you also want some dead zone (both mosfets not conducting) between controlling signals to prevent accidentally shorting the power rail to gnd by opening both mosfets at the same time. Maybe even official stmicroelectronics yt channels covers that, but I've definitely seen it somewhere else too. Complementary and with safe dead zone

Comment: @Ilya I am sorry. I think i did not tell my problem clearly. I already have two complementary PWMs with dead time. But im struggling to adjust their duty cycle. When the duty cycle is %10, only of the PWM's duty cycle is %10. Other one has much more. But i want to have same duty cycle like. I will control output power by changing duty cycle from %10-%50. So i want to have %10-%10, %20-%20, %30-%30, %40-%40 and %50-%50 duty cycles on both PWMs.

Comment: You need to draw pictures of when you want the 2nd output to become active relative to the first output. A picture will help solve this. You only need to show a 10% duty cycle picture.

Comment: @Kırambor I'm not sure as to what exactly is the problem. Still check yt. I think I just typed in STM32 PWM and it gave me videos with adjustable complementary PWM too. You're definitely not the first and not the last to do that, give it a look. I mean, I don't have a library of links in my head, but I know what you're talking about and I've seen it

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for your answer but i could not understand %100. How can i adjust duty cycle if i invert the first PWM ?

Comment: My first comment was made before you replied to Ilya (directly afterwards). I'm deleting that comment now. Draw a picture of what you want.

Comment: You have depicted a quadrature encoder output 50% DT fixed, variable freq. So we cant guess what you really want. You should use some standard PWM techniques to describe. Beside complemetary synchronous PWM, there is also a phase shifted PWM (PS-PWM), I don't recall others.

Comment: @Andyaka I want to have signals like this when the duty cycle is %10. I will increase duty cycle like %10-%20-%30-%40 and %50. So i want signals to stay like this in every step of duty cycle adjustment.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I want to have variable duty cycle(same duty cycles) and variable frequency two complementary PWMs. They will always be complementary no matter what duty cycle is. The problem is when i adjust duty cycle they are not complementary anymore.

Comment: Your depictions description are confusing. You are depicting what you don't want instead of depicting what you want.

Comment: Show, on that new picture how much the dead-time needs to be after pulse 1 completes and after pulse 2 completes. Try and draw it to scale if possible. You can't have 50% duty cycle if you want dead-time. Maybe 48% but you need to show this.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry for missing information. I need 120 nS dead time. When i calculated i got %48.2 duty cycle.

Comment: Well your picture doesn't suggest 120 ns and, should it be after pulse 1 or after pulse 2?

Comment: @Andyaka 120 nS dead time is when the duty cycle is %48.2. It is okey for me to be more when duty cycle is lower. After pulse 1.

Comment: That is for you to decide but somewhere there will be a bigger gap than 120 ns.

Comment: @Andyaka I did not get error or unwanted situation when i have a gap that bigger than 120 nS. So i am okey with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need another approach for making complementary output with dead zones.

If you configure timer CC modules as opposite polarity PWM, you will have synchronized complementary outputs. If you configure the timer with center aligned mode, you will have the ability to make dead zone with manual intervention.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by this source video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMAgD9SS5_E

I needed two out of phase PWMs with complementary PWMNs (plus dead time).
I used TIM1 and TIM8 as well, TIM1 is master, TIM1-CH1 has PWM & PWMN output, TIM1-CH2 as a trigger source, to trigger TIM8 as slave. TIM8-CH3 has another pair of PWM & PWMN output.

By updating the ARR of TIM1 & TIM8, the frequency of both PWMs can be adjusted.

By updating the TIM1-CCR1 & TIM8-CCR3, the % duty cycle of both PWMs can be adjusted.

By kept TIM1-CNT constant (e.g. 1), and updating the TIM8-CNT, the phase shift between the two PWMs can be adjusted.